# Use of gerund having +v-3 form

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This is a extract from Wikipedia. I am sharing the link below.

> After putting his stamp on international hockey arena, and having served his country to reach its pinnacles of glory multiple times. He was a legendary figure in the Indian and world hockey.

[Wikipedia: National Sports Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Sports_Day#India)

Without any finite verb, is the first sentence correct? I can't understand the syntactic use of this sentence. Could we write like this?

Comment: It's not a complete sentence; it's a sentence fragment. Quite common in informal text, but should be avoided in more formal situations.

Comment: Must be a typo. The author of the post must have intended to put a comma and continue the sentence with what follows. You might want to include that actually.

Comment: @fev: Or it's a sentence fragment left stranded when the second half was deleted during editing.

Comment: @PeterShor Possible. It should be corrected, anyway. Doesn't look neat.

Comment: @fev: I don't think it works well with the following sentence, so I suspect it arose in a different way.

Comment: @PeterShor That's why I inserted it. It becomes apparent that there is a problem, that you might be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed incorrect, as the first sentence lacks a main verb. Most likely the "having...times" clause was meant to be a participial phrase modifying "he":

> After putting his stamp on international hockey arena, and having served his country to reach its pinnacles of glory multiple **times, he** was a legendary figure in the Indian and world hockey.